# Can I exclude subpackages when discovering JUnit5 tests?

Tags: junit5

I would like to have a `Launcher` run tests that are in a package (e.g., `com.somewhere`) but not in any subpackages (e.g., `com.somewhere.bad`).

This code runs tests in both the package and subpackage:

```java
import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectPackage;

Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
launcher.execute(request().selectors(selectPackage("com.somewhere").build());
```

I tried excluding subpackages with a filter and a wildcard:

```java
import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectPackage;
import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.PackageNameFilter.excludePackageNames;

launcher.execute(request()
    .selectors(selectPackage("com.somewhere"))
    .filters(excludePackageNames("com.somewhere.*")) // wildcard
    .build());
```

The filter had no effect, leading me to think that wildcards aren't permitted.

The subpackage is excluded only if I filter on its literal name:

```java
import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectPackage;
import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.PackageNameFilter.excludePackageNames;

launcher.execute(request()
    .selectors(selectPackage("com.somewhere"))
    .filters(excludePackageNames("com.somewhere.bad"))
    .build());
```

Is there a way to exclude all subpackages of a package when creating a request? If not, I am planning to filter them out in a `TestExecutionListener` unless someone can suggest a better approach.

Comment: Have you tried excludeClassnamePatterns: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.0/api/org.junit.platform.engine/org/junit/platform/engine/discovery/ClassNameFilter.html#excludeClassNamePatterns(java.lang.String...)?

Comment: @johanneslink I had not. I have tried it now, and it works. Thank you! Do you want to write up an answer, or should I?

Comment: Feel free. I won’t find the time in the next days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment by [johanneslink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32352/johanneslink), the solution was to create a `ClassNameFilter`:

```
launcher.execute(request()
    .selectors(selectPackage("com.somewhere"))
    .filters(ClassNameFilter.excludeClassNamePatterns(
        "com.somewhere\\.[^.]+\\..*"))
    .build());
```

The regular expression excludes class names consisting of:

- `com.somewhere` (the name of the package)
- a period (quoted with backslashes)
- one or more non-periods followed by a period (representing a subpackage name)
- 0 or more characters (further subpackages or the class in a subpackage)